# thrd_busy and mtx_lock()/mtx_timedlock()

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, c11

I have the following questions about C1x mutexes (§7.25.4):

In which situations can `mtx_lock()` return `thrd_busy` instead of blocking? In which situations can `mtx_timedlock()` return `thrd_busy`?

Note that `thrd_busy` is defined in §7.25.1 ¶5 as being returned "*when a resource requested by a test and return function is already in use*".

I would expect `thrd_busy` to be only returned by `mtx_trylock()`, or at most also by `mtx_lock()` when invoked with a `mtx_try` or `mtx_try | mtx_recursive` mutex, but definitely not from `mtx_timedlock()`, which requires a mutex which supports timeout, i.e. a `mtx_timed` or `mtx_timed | mtx_recursive` mutex.

Is this just and oversight in the draft? Or am I missing something?

Comment: We may have to wait for the c1x rationale document for that one.

Comment: Link to the [Draft C1x](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the mutex is not recursive, but you try to lock it in a recursive manner then the behaviour is undefined. However, an implementation could detect this and return `thrd_busy`. (Alternatively, it may block forever, or return `thrd_error`, or `thrd_success`, or format your hard disk.....)

Answer (score 1):

1. mtx_lock() does not return thrd_busy, however, the mtx_trylock function returns thrd_busy if the resource requested is already in use.
2. mtx_timedlock() does not return thrd_busy. The mtx_timedlock function returns thrd_success on success, or thrd_timedout if the time specified was reached without acquiring the requested resource, or thrd_errorif the request could not be honored.