# std::mutex::lock fails on Windows, error code 3

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I use `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` in a proper RAII manner throughout my application:

```
struct Foo {
    int f() const
    {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_mutex);
       return m_i;
    }
private:
   int m_i = 0;
   mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

It always worked, but I've added parallelism to one more class just now, and in this new class `locker` throws `std::system_error`. The problem is here (`xthread` header):

```
inline int _Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_t *_Mtx)
{   // throw exception on failure
    return (_Check_C_return(_Mtx_lock(_Mtx)));
}
```

`_Mtx_lock` returns 3 while the expected value is 0. No idea what 3 means.

VS2013, v120_x64 runtime.

Comment: Post the code that instantiates the mutex.

Comment: @WernerErasmus: expanded the question.

Comment: Give us enough code to reproduce the problem. Or check the call stack when the error occurs and it may be obvious.

Comment: Make your mutex mutable... You're modifying it's state from a const function. It should not compile, imo

Comment: Also, might be compiler issue. I'll write default constructor that default initialize mutex.

Comment: This fails to compile [here](https://ideone.com/nO330I)

Comment: @WernerErasmus: well sure it is mutable, I thought that's obvious enough to omit from the question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I can't give you enough code to reproduce the problem, it's a decently big project and I don't have a slightest idea what triggers the issue. Which is why I need to know what error code 3 means. The callstack is perfectly fine, except return code is 0 for success and 3 when it fails.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, accepted, but giving us code that doesn't compile detracts us from the real problem.

Comment: Also, prefix _ is reserved for the standard.

Comment: @WernerErasmus: right, I'll do my best avoiding low quality code snippets in my questions. As for the underscore prefix, it doesn't seem to be forbidden in local scope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/634821

Comment: If anyone wants to experiment, it's an open-source project on Github. I could simply commit the faulty code. It needs Qt to compile, though.

Comment: Error code 3 seems to be the value of `_Thrd_busy` at the top of xthreads.h.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe. In the code presented I see no obvious errors. I might clone the project some time. I have Qt. Could it be that mutex is locked recursively? Does not seem that way in code presented. I can't find documentation for the return values of Mtx_lockx

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Did you look closely at every function in the callstack to see if it's doing anything related to the mutex?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error as mentioned by @Phantom (_Thrd_busy) implies that the lock had been recursively taken. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312971/thrd-busy-and-mtx-lock-mtx-timedlock)

Comment: That's it, switching to `std::recursive_mutex` solved the problem! I should probably refactor my code to avoid recursive locking.